# how to use proxies with scrapy-requests and scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-request

I'm hoping someone can help me, I'm trying to use the scrapy-requests package with scrapy so I can render the full page. (https://pypi.org/project/scrapy-requests/) I can't seem to pass the proxies to it, I see that

```
    from scrapy_requests import HtmlRequest

yield HtmlRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, render=True)
```

inherits for scrapy. requests I tried passing the proxy through meta argument like how you would do

```
yield scrapy.Request(url=url,meta=proxy)
```

but that didn't work. SO I started messing with the middleware it comes with and I edited the spider_open function to this

```
def spider_opened(self, spider: Spider) -> None:
    """Open HTMLSession when spider starts"""
    s = HTMLSession()
    s.proxies = {'http': 'http://23.236.168.81:1111'}
    self.session = s
```

if I have the render option set to False it works but as soon as I set it to true it reverts back to my original IP Any help appreciated.

thank you

Comment: Maybe it should be `s.proxies = {'https': '<your proxy URL>'}`? Are you trying to open HTTPS page?

Answer (score 0):

heres the answer if anyone ever needs to do the same thing
will only use 1 proxy on every spider open/close so if you need to loop it i would just write powershell script in a while loop  scrapy crawl myspider

```
 def spider_opened(self, spider: Spider) -> None:
        """Open HTMLSession when spider starts"""

        prox = random.choice(Pr.ROTATING_PROXY_LIST)
        s = HTMLSession(browser_args=[f'--proxy-server={prox}', f'--user-agent{ua.random}'])
        self.session = s
```